# Botframework with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, botframework

I want to implement BotFramework in a WordPress but in any way or form, it's not working properly.

I used different scripts but got to the same wrong result.

one:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='height: 38px; position: fixed;
                     bottom: 0; z-index: 1000; background-color: red'>
                     <div id='botTitleBar' style='height: 38px; width: 400px; 
                     position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'></div>
                     [advanced_iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/..." 
                     width="100%" height="600"]</div>"; 
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
        if (e.target.matches('#botTitleBar')) { 
            var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv'); 
            botDiv.style.height = botDiv.style.height == '600px' ? '38px' : '600px';
        };
    });
}());
</script>
```

it's giving me the banner but not opening the chat when pressed.
in other case the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: 'key' }),
        userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
        username: 'Web Chat User',
        locale: 'en-US',
        botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
        userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but in this case, it's doing nothing.
help, please :(

Comment: In which file does the first script you list exist in and how is it referenced in relation to the html page?

Comment: this script is located in the HTML widget of the WordPress main page. so it's living on its own. the first part of the script is creating a footer with the chat bar in the closed state. but when I press is to envoke a click event, nothing happens.

Comment: Two questions...what widget(s) or plugin(s) are you using in conjunction with this? Also, are you passing a token or secret for the Direct Line token value?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how your environment is structured, so hopefully, this translates but I was able to accomplish this. I'm running this locally having spun up a WP site on a WAMP server.

First, I generate a token by making an API call to

`https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate`.

If you're already generating a token, then skip to the next section. If not, you can reference this code, found [here](https://github.com/stevkan/directline-token) (if of interest).

On WP, I am using a plugin called 'WP Coder' This allows you to enter in the necessary components while letting the plugin 'make it work' in the page. I tried hand-coding it in, but the WP page wasn't playing nice and this plugin was.

Once the plugin is installed, put this in the 'HTML code' section:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>WebChat</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Followed by this in the 'CSS code' section:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%
}

body {
    margin: 0
}

#webchat,
#webchat>* {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Btw, if you set the height to 100% for '#webchat' the chat will continuously scroll down the page, as entries are made, forcing the user to have to 'scroll after it'. Outside of that, adjust it as you will.

Under 'JS Code', add the following. Please note, that I'm generating a token locally. You will need to update this to match your method of token generation:

```js
( async function () {
        const res = await fetch( 'http://localhost:3979/directline/token', { method: 'POST' } );
        const { token } = await res.json();
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( { token } )
        }, document.getElementById( 'webchat' ) );
      } )();
```

Next, under 'Include files' enter the two following JS files as URLs (individually):

```
https://unpkg.com/markdown-it/dist/markdown-it.min.js
https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js
```

Lastly, take the Publish 'shortcode' (mine looks like this `[WP-Coder id="1"]`) and place it on your page. This is found in the WP Coder plugin.

At this point, it should work for you. If not, I would look closely at how you are generating and passing the token.

[image]

[image]

Hope of help!