# 'Auto scroll' not working On Microsoft-bot-Framework (Python SDK based)

Tags: python, wordpress, botframework, autoscroll

I have some issue about microsoft-botframework.

I made a chatbot using microsoft-botframework Python SDK.

So I deploy it as Webchat , I attached this on my website, Wordpress.

However, the **Auto-scroll on card doesn't work.**

When new card appear, Auto scroll doesn't working.

So this is my critical Issue and I really want  someone help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1031) in WebChat. There is a work around where you can use a custom WebChat Activity Middleware that scrolls the last message into view when the chat window receives a new message. Take a look at the code snippet below.

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {},
    ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY_FULFILLED') {
            document.querySelector('ul[role="list"]').lastChild.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
        }
        return next(action);
    }
);

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    store
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi tdurnford, Thanks for apply. well  this is java script code right?  I dont know how I paste this code on my python code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This middleware goes on the WebChat side. There is now way to manipulate the client from the bot.

Comment: well I paste my webchat using iframe on Wordpress. is there any other way to solve this problem ? thank you/

Comment: There isn't a way around this issue using an iFrame. You can, however, use a Wordpress Plugin to add WebChat to your website and use the middleware above. Checkout this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263284/botframework-with-wordpress) for more details on adding WebChat your site.

Comment: @tdurnford - I have a similar issue with trying to setup a Directline webchat on Squarespace. Where do I put the code snippet above, do I include it in my chatbot’s index.js file where all my other chatbot middleware is set up?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I have a strange usage (directline embedded in a Sharepoint page, ie. not absolute/fixed position):

```
 const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {},
    ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY_FULFILLED') {
            var scrollDiv = $('ul[role="list"]').first().parent();
            scrollDiv.scrollTop(scrollDiv[0].scrollHeight);
        }
        return next(action);
    }
  );    


  window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
      token: 'mySecret'
    }),
    store,
    ...
```

Hope it can help someone else.

If you don't want to use jQuery, replace the 2 scrollDiv lines with:

```
var scrollDiv = document.querySelector('ul[role="list"]').parentElement;
scrollDiv.scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollHeight;
```