# Microsoft Bot framework v4 change place holder text, status message, auto scroll

Tags: botframework

Multiple questions about Bot Framework V4.

1. Change the input field place holder text

[image]

2. Change the status message

[image]

3. Auto scroll on new message
   On new message, chat bot is not scrolling down.
   This issue is already asked here - ['Auto scroll' not working On Microsoft-bot-Framework (Python SDK based)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614457/auto-scroll-not-working-on-microsoft-bot-framework-python-sdk-based)
   https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1031#issuecomment-459397736
   Tried the workaround solution for  web chat, but with adaptive cards taking some time to load, this solution doesn't scroll down fully.

   - Added a timeout of 3 sec, it works, but not ideal solution as there is a  lag in scroll.
   - My Adaptive cards json is added to https://www.qnamaker.ai/, is that the reason for delay in loading?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can change the `sendBox` default text by accessing the property via `store`, like so:

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
    payload: { text: 'You got this!'}
  });
});
```

[image]

2. The ability to customize the `timestamp` is, at this time, still a feature request. If this feature would be valuable to you, I would suggest you upvote and/or add your voice to the [conversation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1571).
3. My strong suspicion is, yes, the lag on rendering the adaptive card is due to QnAMaker. Or, more specifically, due to an API call and needing to wait for the returned result.

Comment: Steven, is this just for custom web chat using directline, or is it possible to do customizations like these when using the OOTB web channel?

Comment: These customizations only apply to [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). They do not apply to Web Chat as a ABS channel (using the embedded code).